# Meaning of "acknowledged in a way" in the given sentence

Tags: meaning, ellipsis

Here is the sentence:

> Female sexuality within the working classes of Western Europe was
>   **acknowledged in a way** that it was not within the middle class.

Here is a more detailed excerpt:

"Female sexuality within the working classes of Western Europe
was acknowledged in a way that it was not within the middle class.
Demographic evidence reveals a sharp rise in illegitimacy between 1750
and 1850. In Frankfurt, Germany, for example, where the illegitimacy rate
had been a mere 2 per cent in the early 1700s, reached 25 per cent in 1850.
In Bordeaux, France, in 1840, one-third of the recorded births were illegitimate."

Comment: The *ellipsis* tag added suggests "Female sexuality within the **working** classes of Western Europe was acknowledged in a way that it was not [acknowledged] within the **middle** class."

Comment: Did you check the definition of " acknowledge"? Otherwise, could you add what the specific problem is? I suppose it could be *acknowledged*, "in a way", the relationship of the joined phrases, or something else.

Comment: I cannot figure out the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very euphemistic sentence.  I read it as

> It was accepted that working class women across Western Europe enjoyed sexual  activities.  Whereas Middle and upper class women were
>   not accepted as enjoying sexual activities, they were still meant to
>   only have sex to satisfy their husband.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of "Acknowledged in a way, just means that, you are acknowledging the person or people you are referring to.

For example:

Female sexuality within the working classes of Western Europe was *acknowledged in a way* that it was not within the middle class.

This just means, that the Female Sexuality, was acknowledged by doing a variety of actions to respect them. Like giving them money, or doing a parade.

Thus, that is why *acknowledged in a way*  is put into that sentence, yet with a context, with a simple meaning behind it!!! (XD)